# Can I install the current version of Unity in an older version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, 11.10, unity, kernel, power-management

Is it possible to install current version of unity of 11.10 in 10.10 as I'm fed up with the power issues of current kernel version and would like to revert back.

If I revert back to previous kernel 2.6.38 on 11.10 can I solve the power issues and heating issues? And is it possible to install 2.6.38 on 11.10?

Comment: simple answer - no you can't install unity 11.10 onto 10.10.  Why dont you install 11.10 and then try the 2.6.35/38 mainline kernel.  Let us know what you find out.

Comment: No, Unity in 11.10 uses Gnome 3, 10.10 comes with Gnome 2, if w/e previous kernel worked for you then install it.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible"? Yes, it's Ubuntu and free software, so it's possible. But it is not practical.

Ubuntu started the transition from Gnome 2 to Gnome 3 with 11.04. Unity relies on some technologies from Gnome 3, like GObject. This could be fixed by replacing GObject from Gnome3 with GObject from Gnome 2, but that would require a little work. Unity also relies heavily on a very new version of Compiz. I know less about that, but I would assume that it is highly dependent on the X server.

In other words, you'd have to port many different things and it'd be a lot of work. 10.10 has less than 6 months left to live, so that's certainly not going to happen. If anything, it would be ported to 10.04, but that's highly unlikely.